# PHP printing out without leaving the page... How?

Tags: php, printf

I recently started to learn **PHP** but everytime i want to print out a message or a result it redirects me to a clean different page only displaying a result of output...

Its a basic code, for example:

```
<input type="number" name="x"><br>
<input type="number" name="y"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Multiply">
```

and php...

```
$x = $_GET["x"];
$y = $_GET["y"];
printf("%f<br>", $x*$y);
```

i just want a clean output without redirecting me somewhere else, for example i want output to be right bellow "Multiply button"... i searched on *net but i didn't found enything... maybe i can't express correctly sry..

Comment: Without having to reload the page, you'll need to use some sort of AJAX.

Comment: you can use `JS` for this and for more complex server side queries you would use `AJAX`

Comment: Have you added FORM tag?

Comment: It just does not happen. To do this you need to use AJAX.

Comment: @Kamal form tag? noo, btw i dont want to use anything besides php and html if possible